# I have this error when trying to install wire-server/ansible

Tags: python, kubernetes, ansible, python-poetry

I had run the following command `poetry install` when following instruction on [this page](https://docs.wire.com/how-to/install/kubernetes.html#ansible-kubernetes).

I had received an `RuntimeError`, does any one know how to solve it?

```
RuntimeError
  Poetry could not find a pyproject.toml file in /home/kodi66/wire-server-deploy/ansible or its parents

  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/poetry/core/factory.py:369 in locate
      365│             if poetry_file.exists():
      366│                 return poetry_file
      367│ 
      368│         else:
    → 369│             raise RuntimeError(
      370│                 "Poetry could not find a pyproject.toml file in {} or its parents".format(
      371│                     cwd
      372│                 )
      373│             )
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if those instructions are out-of-date; looking at the repository history, the use of poetry was removed in January in commit [567dcce](https://github.com/wireapp/wire-server-deploy/commit/567dcce8f66769ff5fec802e34015a0053c5cef7). The commit message reads (partially):

> Use nix to provide hegemony binary dependencies and switch to git submodules for ansible dedencies (#404)
>
> - remove poetry, use Nix to provide the ansible we need
>
> Also, set NIX_PATH when entering via direnv, so nix-shell does the right
> thing when in there.
>
> Move to ansible 2.9
> [...]

You probably want to file a bug against the [wire-docs](https://github.com/wireapp/wire-docs) repository.